# The Mystery of the Vanishing EF Call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, entity-framework-5

Today I got an emergency call from the users on our ASP.NET production system.  Some users (not all) were unable to enter certain data.  The user posted the data, and the system then froze; the call never returned.

We tried to repro the problem on the QA system (which has a fresh restore of production data), and could not.  I then ran from my dev environment and connected directly to the production DB, masquerading as one of the affected users.  Again, no problem.  Conclusion: there must be some kind of issue in the production environment, probably somewhere in the IIS process that's hosting the website.

So I fired up Visual Studio on the production server, and attached to the IIS process *(Kids, don't do this at home!)*, set a breakpoint in the offending code, logged in as the user, and attempted to save the data.  Hit the breakpoint and stepped line by line, until I hit a line of code like this:

```
try
{
  ...
  using (var db = new MyDataContext())
  {
    ...
    var fooToUpdate = db.Foos.Single(f => f.ID == fooId); // <-- THIS LINE
    ...
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // some error logging
}
```

After hitting "step" on that line, the thread simply vanished.  Disappeared without a trace.  I put a sniffer on the database, and no query was fired; needless to say there was no DB locking involved.  No exception was thrown.  The code entered Entity Framework and never left.

The way the data is is that every user has a different and unique `fooId` for every day, so no other user will have the same `fooId`.  Most users were able to load their Foo, but a select handful of users fail consistently to load their personal Foo.  I tried running the query to load the Foo in a SSMS window; no trouble at all.  The only time it fails is in this particular IIS process, on the production server.

Now, I could just recycle the app pool or restart IIS, and that would probably paper over the problem.  But something similar happened a week ago, and we couldn't trace it then, either.  So we reset IIS then, hoping the problem would go away.  And it did, for a week.  And now it's back.

Does anyone have any ideas how it is possible for a thread to simply vaporize like this?  Is Norman Bates hiding behind the EF door?

Comment: Did you tried to look in Event Viewer on production, does it have any meaningful message (if any) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the EF part was a red herring after all.  I went and downloaded Telerik's JustDecompile and JustCode, in the hope of stepping into the EF code, but when I stepped in to that line, I found myself not in the `Single()` extension method, but inside one of my own method calls - that I *thought* I had executed on the previous line.  Evidently the code was not perfectly in sync with the version in production.

> **LESSON 1:** If you attach to a process, your execution point may not be where you think it is, if your code is not identical to the code that was 
>   compiled into that process.

So anyway, now that I could step into the code without decompiling anything, the first thing I noticed was:

```
lock (_lockObj)
{
  ...
}
```

And when I tried to step into it, it froze there.  Smoking gun.

So somewhere, some other thread is locking this object.  Looked at other places where the lock is invoked, leading to a spaghetti of dependencies, along with another code-locked segment, with several DB calls and even a transaction boundary.  It could be a code lock / db transaction deadlock, though a brief scan of the code in the DB transaction failed to pick up any contenders within the life of the transaction for blocking anything else.  Plus, there's the evidence of the DB not showing any blocking or open transactions.  Rather, it may just be the the fact of a few hundred queued up long-running processes, all inside code locks inside code locks, and in the end it all looks something like the West Side Highway at 17:05 on a Friday, with a jackknifed trailer truck lying across 3 lanes approaching the GW bridge.

> **LESSON 2:** Code locks are dangerous, not only - but especially - when used in conjunction with DB transactions.  Try to find ways to make your code thread safe without using code locks.  And if you really must use code locks, make sure you get in and out as quickly as possible.  Don't give your thread a magazine to read while it's occupying the only stall, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that the thread did not magically vaporize, we could speculate some of the more likely options:

1. The debugger had a hard time following the production code compiled in Release mode. Just because debugging Release code works 90% of the time, don't fall under the illusion that it is dependable. Optimized code can very quickly throw the debugger off the track of actual execution. When this happens, it will look like the thread just vanished.
2. Assuming the thread does legitimately enter the call and not return (which seems to be supported by the original complaint of the application "freezing"), then the most likely scenario is a deadlock of some type. `EntityFramework` deadlocks are not common, but not unheard of either. The most common issues I'm aware of usually involve `TransactionScope` or `CommitableTransaction`. Are you using any transactions in the omitted code sections?

Comment: There are transaction boundaries elsewhere in that method, but we are not inside a transaction boundary at this execution point.

Comment: Technically a deadlock scenario could also be potentially initiated by any other application thread accessing the `EntityFramework`. You might want to search online for various methods of detecting deadlock to see if this is a possible culprit.

Comment: But no call was recorded as making it to the database, which is where a deadlock would occur. The problem happened before execution ever reached the DB.

Comment: It's possible the deadlock is not occurring in SQL Server. Sometimes deadlocks from critical sections, for example, hang on higher level methods that appear, on the surface, to be totally unrelated. This might be one of those issues that calls for a memory dump to be examined in WinDbg / SOS. If you go this route, start with the `!analyze -hang -v` command.

Comment: I think I've solved it.  See my answer.  +1 to you for your logical and useful comments - thanks!

Comment: Nice job tracking down the location of the deadlock. In my experience, a common source of these type of deadlocks is from inside the logging of a `catch { }` clause. For example, if a file logger or event log logger invokes on a separate thread. So thread 1, inside a lock, throws an exception, which triggers another thread 2 (during logging) to indirectly run into the same lock. This is common because during the exception logging, devs usually try to capture as much info as possible from the offending object, thus hitting its properties and/or methods and usually bumping into the locks.